# Parallel queries with reactive Panache

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache, quarkus-hibernate-reactive

I understand from https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/32790 and the linked explanation that you can't have parallel unis reusing a session. From my understanding of it, you should be able to achieve the parallel aspect of it by having a different session for each Uni.

However, how is this supposed to work with Panache? Imagine the following example (I have other with two different `PanacheQuery` running in parallel but this is the simpler one to look at without much context):

```java
    @WithSession
    public Uni<SearchSessionsResult> search(...) {
        final PanacheQuery<Session> query = this.find(logic with the received parameters)
        return Uni.combine()
            .all()
            .unis(
                query.list(), 
                query.pageCount(), 
                query.count()
            )
            .combinedWith(entities, pageCount, totalEntries) -> [some more business logic]);
    }
```

This will fail with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal pop() with non-matching JdbcValuesSourceProcessingState` becasue of the three unis running in parallel, which is expected. Since chaining the three unis is a bit impractical and doing things sequentially might have a big impact if you a bigger number of unis (and/or they are more complex), I wanted to follow the approach of having each uni run with a different session, but I'm unsure how to achieve this while still sticking to Panache

I tried wrapping the unis with `Panache.withSession`, like so:

```java
    @WithSession
    public Uni<SearchSessionsResult> search(...) {
        final PanacheQuery<Session> query = this.find(logic with the received parameters)
        return Uni.combine()
            .all()
            .unis(
                Panache.withSession(query::list),
                Panache.withSession(query::pageCount),
                Panache.withSession(query::count)
            )
            .combinedWith(entities, pageCount, totalEntries) -> [some more business logic]);
    }
```

But the result is the same because Panache will reuse the current open reactive session for all unis. I also tried injecting the `SessionFactory` and opening sessions myself (I confess I don't know too much about how to do this, but I tried to follow the logic in the `Panache` class of opening the session and chaining a uni afterwards)

```java
    @Inject
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @WithSession
    public Uni<SearchSessionsResult> search(...) {
        final PanacheQuery<Session> query = this.find(logic with the received parameters)
        return Uni.combine()
            .all()
            .unis(
                sessionFactory.openSession().chain(session -> query.list().eventually(session::close)),
                sessionFactory.openSession().chain(session -> query.pageCount().eventually(session::close)),
                sessionFactory.openSession().chain(session -> query.count().eventually(session::close))
            )
            .combinedWith(entities, pageCount, totalEntries) -> [some more business logic]);
    }
```

And got the same result. So the question in essence is simple: How can I execute multiple DB queries in parallel using Panache?
NOTE: The first example worked in Quarkus 2

Comment: just need to ask - what is your goal here? using separate sessions also means separate connections and separate transactions. Giving you performance overhead and possibly inconsistent data.

Comment: @MaxRydahlAndersen that's true indeed. My goal is not "use multiple sessions", that's just the path I think I'm forced to take. The goal is "how to do queries in parallel". In this case, to return a paginated list of entities, I need to know the entities themselves and info about the pages, so that on the next request the client can get the next page. I have another example where the client wants to associate many users with another entity, and I need to verify if the users exist first. If they send me 10 users, I'd have to chain 10 requests. Doing it in multiple sessions there would be ok

Comment: This article has more inforative content related to this topic, and thought I would post here - https://blog.lunatech.com/posts/2023-05-19-hibernate-reactive-gotchas